# Extract digits after a word occurrence

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a Name column and a Log column.

```
Name            Log
Michelle        Bad news travels id 54585 fast.
Lucy            Barking dogs id 545584 seldom bite.
Green           Beauty is in the id 85955 eyes of the beholder.
Gail            Beggars 123 can't be ID 4658 choosers.
```

I want to extract only the ID digits from log column. The output should be like this:

```
Name        ID
Michelle    54585
Lucy        545584
Green       85955
Gail        4658
```

I tried to use the following query:

```
select name
     , substring(log from E'^(.*?)[id< ]') as id
from mytable;
```

However, I cannot have the output I need. Note that the word ID could be capitalized or not.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with fancy regular expressions.  Here is one way that I do this with nested calls to `translate()`:

```
select translate(col,
                 '0123456789' || translate(col, '0123456789', ''),
                 '0123456789')
from (select cast('asdg sgafadsf 123123 .,sdfa' as varchar(255)) as col) t;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3368).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, What should I do if I have the following: "Beggars 123 can't be ID 4658 choosers" ?  Isn't it return: 1234658 ?  That is a concern to me. I would the output to be only digits after the word ID. To avoid this situation I need something like, return me only the 10 characters after the word ID, but only the digits. Thanks,

Comment: @SamuelDonadelli . . . Then you would have a different question.  Your question explicitly states:  "I want to extract only the ID digits from log column".

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include the exception. I will try again. Thanks anyways, Samuel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.name
        , regexp_replace (m.log, e'.* [iI][Dd] ([0-9]*).*', '\1', '') AS id
FROM meuk m
        ;
```

Result:

```
INSERT 0 4
   name   |   id   
----------+--------
 Michelle | 54585
 Lucy     | 545584
 Green    | 85955
 Gail     | 4658
(4 rows)
```